# How to make a range slider with 4 steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, slider

I want to make a range slider with 4 steps in jQuery. See the attached image[image]

Problem is I don't know where to start. I found [this reference](http://codefusionlab.com/slider_steps.html) and I'm wondering if you could point me in the right direction. Any tips or references are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help you

https://github.com/freqdec/fd-slider

https://github.com/fryn/html5slider

These are vanilla JS implementations of `<input type="range" />` tha can be styled as a slider

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery UI you simply set the `step` to increment for each area, lets say this example:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 3,
    step: 1 // so we'll move from 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 (4 locations)
});
```

Doing this logic you'll be able to move to 4 different locations. Incremental each time by 1 in this case.

More info here: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

Comment: Is there some other way of doing it without jqueryUI?